# phonegap hydration is enabled?

Tags: html, css, phonegap, hydration

Home come, can i only go online with my app if, hydration is enbabled in the phonegap settings?

I thought is was because i didnt have a keystore, but i got that, so it is not that.

It is very important that my app is able to go online, and i dont get why hydration needs to be enabled to do so.

```
  <div id="scroll">
   <a href="https://www.lokalbolig.dk/bolig/villa/fredericia/7000/rubinvej--11/38-V00060/64260/billeder">
    <img src="img/boliger/antal3/den fjerde/lasmere1.png" width="40%"  alt=""/></a>
```

Comment: your code is not properly inserted. Can you edit your answer and insert it into a code snippet? It is found on the toolbar at the top of the editor. Thanks!

Comment: No i know but is it a code Thing since it only works with in hydration?